# AD security group not resolving users for one Web application but for others

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have two web applications, web1.myfarm.com and web2.myfarm.com. An AD security group "Domain\Farm_Users" is granted access on both of the web applications. The group members in "Domain\Farm_Users" were able to access the sites for both web applications.

Now i am facing an issue that group members can access web2.myfarm.com with same "Domain\Farm_Users" group but not web1.myfarm.com. They get access denied error while accessing the web1.

Any thoughts?

Comment: all users getting the access denied? any change to that web application? make sure group is still added to web applications? at which level you add the group?

Comment: Yes all users are getting access denied. No major change to the web application explicitly but we have recently installed some windows security patches on servers. The group is still added at root level on the site.

Comment: could you pelase try to access the site from farm admin account? also check the logs why it is getting the access denied...also from central admin > upgrade migration > check the status of database if it says upgrade required?

Comment: Site is accessible from all other accounts, other SP and AD groups. Even if we add the group members directly to the site, it works. The DB status is currently "Failed". If i check for servers status, it says upgrade blocked and installation required. Looks like i am missing something big in my farm. But i was missing these component since a long time and issue didn't occur. Not making any sense to me.

Comment: This is giving me hint your farm is not healthy state and you have to patch it. Sometime problem happen with one Web app or site collection due to upgrade...Also try one more thing, remove the group complety from Site collections/webapp, recycle the app pool of the web app, then re add the group.

Comment: Tried the mentioned trick of recycling but no gain yet. I think i need to first get my servers on same patch level.

Comment: that is basic thing...you have to update ur servers....is their only 1 site collection in the webapp or more than one? u can try to create a new site collection in that web app and try again.

Comment: It works fine for other site collections of the web app. Only creating issue with 2 site collections which are our major ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha. Issue resolved.

1. Go to site permissions, Click the SP group which contains the AD group, **Click the AD group** and remove it by clicking **Delete User from Site Collection**.[image]
2. Add the group back in the SP group. It worked...!

   ---

**P.S : Previously i was deleting the AD group directly from SP group using "Remove Users From Group" option.**